# Pgfplots histogram with density less than one

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot two histograms over each other in order to compare densities of two different datasets.

The problem is that the second dataset has less observations than the first one, and I want its total density to be relative to the first one (maybe that was slightly unclear).

The two histograms below should hopefully illustrate the problem. I want the density-histogram (the bottom one) to look like the top histogram which is without density. Any ideas?

If not, is it possible to put all the missing value equal to some other number (say 0) and simply not draw the bar of those specific observations?

Without density:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend entries={$k=1$,$k=2$} ]
\addplot+[hist={bins=6}, thick, draw=blue, fill = blue, opacity=0.4]
table[col sep=comma, y index=0] {./fig/degree_distribution.dat};
%
\addplot+[hist={bins=5}, thick, draw=red,  fill=red, opacity = 0.4] %replace 0 with [space] in .dat
table[col sep=comma, y index=1] {./fig/degree_distribution.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: I want the bottom picture to look like this]

With density:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend entries={$k=1$,$k=2$} ]
\addplot+[hist={bins=6, density}, thick, draw=blue, fill = blue, opacity=0.4]
table[col sep=comma, y index=0] {./fig/degree_distribution.dat};
%
\addplot+[hist={bins=5, density}, thick, draw=red,  fill=red, opacity = 0.4] %replace 0 with [space] in .dat
table[col sep=comma, y index=1] {./fig/degree_distribution.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: This one should like like the top one!]

**EDIT:**
Here is a small sample of the data:

```
%col0, col1
3,3
3,3
2,2
3, 
3,2
2,2
1, 
4,2
```

Hence, some of the observations in `col1` are missing.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence "The problem is that the second dataset has less observations than the first one, and I want its total density to be relative to the first one": The density histogram, by definition, doesn't care about the number of samples. It's normalized so that the total area under the curve is unity. Doing this allows you to compare two distributions: the bottom diagram is exactly what you need. It seems like you want to "squash" the plot for `k=2`, but that would actually make it *harder* to compare the two distributions. Let's say you're trying to assess the probability

Comment: ... of getting a number between `2` and `3`. If you were to interpret your top diagram as a density histogram, you'd come to the conclusion that getting a number between `2` and `3` is less likely when `k=2` than when `k=1`. In reality however, the opposite is true: you're almost twice as likely to get a number between `2` and `3` when `k=2`.

Comment: Jake: Sure, but it always depends on what you would like to look at. Here I am interested in a specific application to microeconomics. It is not probabilities per se I'm interested in, but a population of some size n normalized to 1 in `k=1`. However, in `k=2` some of the observations from `k=1` have "left the model". Hence, the total population should now be less than 1, as well as the distribution of certain attributes of the population (1,2,...,7) changes when the "state of nature" changes. This is what I want to illustrate. Thanks for the comment though, I see that I could be more clear!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you need to have a plot which doesn't add up to unity since some data *left the model* and this should represent the distribution in the face of absent information... That's actually what @Jake said in a nutshell. You might want to renormalize the column based on the missing amount then, is that correct?

Comment: @user3218615: Ah, okay. So you want to be able to state things like "With k=2, 30% of the *original population* fall between 2 and 3", right?

Comment: @Jake: Yes that is correct. I guess that since the total mass normalizes to unity by definition under `hist=density`, would it be possible to somehow set the values of the "missing" observation to another value (say 1000) and just not plot that specific bar? Then the integral of the remaining mass will be less than 1, and the two distributions would be comparable for this specific application.